# MVC3 Binding model (some fields) to  the view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Binding model to the view.

my model Person has {Id,Title,Address...etc)

In my controller I want to retrieve some fields 
e.g:

```
 var model = from p in db.Person where p.jobtype == 1 
             select new Person { Title = p.Title, Address = p.Address};
 return View(model);
```

also tried to to use anonymous type and it doesn't work:

```
 var model = from p in db.Person where p.jobtype == 1 
             select new { p.Title, p.Address};
 return View(model);
```

In my view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Person>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <div>@item.Title</div>}  >FAILS
```

If I retrieve full object then it works, how do I retrieve some fields using anonymous type or\and using my model.... plz provide the correct syntax. Thanks

Comment: Does `from p in Person` work?

Comment: updated. db.Person would work, but fails at the view

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and don't use data models as view models. Create a ViewModel for your view, and then populate it with the data model.

Comment: you right, sorry I updated the question I meant to say jobtype = 1 , I need to get the (multiple) person object into the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your View is requiring the Model to be `Enumerable` then it needs to be `AsEnumerable` in your select statement.

```
var model = (from p in db.Person
            where p.jobtype == 1
            select p).AsEnumerable();

return View(model);
```

and then

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Person>

@foreach (var item in Model.ToList()) {
<div>@item.Title</div>}
```

---

Alternatively, Since you just need a list at the end of the day, and you "should" be using a ViewModel, I suggest the following.

**ViewModel**

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
var person = (from p in db.Person
            where p.jobtype == 1
            select p);

PersonViewModel model = Mapper.Map<Person, PersonViewModel>(person);

return View(model.ToList());
```

**View**

```
@model List<Demo.ViewModels.PersonViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<div>@item.Title</div>}
```

*note: I used AutoMapper in the above example*
*<sub>I don't have my IDE in front of me, so I'm not sure if this is perfect.</sub>*

Comment: I though I should only create a viewModel if I want to join multiple models into one and display in the view. I am using 1 model and I want to show some fields of that model... do I still need to create a viewModel?

Comment: A ViewModel will be used on Every View. It's the right way to separate concerns. Example: does your `Person` have a `Password` field? Do you need it in the View? Probably not, so don't pass it.

Comment: k, Is it possible to create anonymous type object and pass that object to the view? or my only solution is viewmodel?

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can do pretty much whatever you like in your programming. I'm only suggesting the ViewModel because it's the "right" way to do it. It's minimal code, *and* you can use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map your ViewModels to your Models.

Comment: got it, thx for your help, could you please explain me when it is good to use anonymous type object?

Comment: Answer is incrorrect:  `p.jobtype = 1` should be  `p.jobtype == 1`

Comment: @MatteKarla, then edit the error instead of down voting. Did you notice my comment at the bottom regarding not having the IDE?

Comment: @Ben you can't use Anonymous Types in a strongly typed View since the Complier has no idea what the Type Name is. [See this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_3.0#Anonymous_types)

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, I must edit at least 6 characters so I can't fix it. sorry :-(

Comment: Do you nead `.AsEnumerable()`? Linq-queries normally return `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, and both work fine with a IEnumerable<T>-model in the view.

Comment: I personally prefer returning `AsQueryable()` so that I can run linq queries on my objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ToList() :

```
List<person> model = (from p in db.Person 
                      where p.jobtype == 1 
                      select p).ToList();
return View(model);
```

In your view :

```
 @model List<person>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 }
```

Comment: Answer is incrorrect: `p.jobtype = 1` should be `p.jobtype == 1`

Comment: It is not the point! Ben explain that it works but fails at the view.

Comment: @TwTw you should know that simple typos don't merit an edit... we perfectionists instantly go to the down vote. * sarcasm *

Comment: MatteKarla : Because someone downvote your answer you downvote mine? It's not fair!

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: Simple typos in both question and response causing code to not compile, is that perfectionist? I'm sorry that I don't have edit-rights and I have undone the downvotes.

Comment: You're right @MatteKarla, I (and probably TwTw too) just did a copy/paste of his original code as a baseline to get started.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you call your data `db.People` or something like that.

You should use `p.ID == 3` instead of `p.ID = 3`.

If your intention is to only select one Person and display then use `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()` to get only a single Person-entry.

```
var model = (from p in db.Person where p.ID == 3 
             select p.Title).First();
```

Then in your model don't use IEnumerable, just use:

```
 @model Demo.Models.Person
      <div>@item.Title</div>
```

EDIT:
after you updated question to contain p.jobtype instead of p.ID to select multiple I would recommend using a specific ViewModel for the data you wish to select.
If all you want is Title then you could use

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var title in Model) {
 <div>@title</div>}
```

But I would recommend using a specific ViewModel with only the fields you require, for example:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then `select new PersonViewModel {Name = p.Name, Title = p.Title }`
and of course use that model in the view: `@model IEnumerable<PersonViewModel>`.

Comment: He needs the Person to be `Enumerable`, so `First` doesn't work.

Comment: I only answered the original question, asked for p.ID = 3, So I thought he only wanted a single Person. My response states "If your intention is to only select one Person ...", why the downvote?

Comment: Ah yes, but there is more evidence in the original question pointing to `Enumerable<T>` as well as `foreach` that the `where` clause was the bit that was out of place.